# How to remove background of images with the magick package?

Tags: r, imagemagick, ggimage

Is it possible to remove the background of images with the `magick` package?

I know how to use edge detection with Gimp/Inkscape to crop out silhouettes; however, I'm looking to automate the process for a large batch of images with `R`.

My ultimate goal is to use the `ggimage` package to plot these images as `x,y` coordinates but the background of these images is currently overlapping the plot (the dog compared to fink)

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

set.seed(2017-02-21)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                image = sample(c("http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/silhouettes/2015/05/cairn-terrier-black-silhouette.svg", "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
                )

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image))
```

[image: output]

One can trim the edges of an image using image magick's `image_trim()`

```
img <- image_read_svg("http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/silhouettes/2015/05/cairn-terrier-black-silhouette.svg")
image_trim(img)
```

but this isn't exactly what I would like.

Any ideas?

Comment: `image_transparent()` will let you change a colour - still might be worth doing manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `image_transparent()` function does this, e.g.:

```
logo <- image_read("logo:")
image_transparent(logo, 'white')
```

The white parts of the image will be made transparent, which should be enough for the simple image in your example.

Answer (score -3):

see my answer in https://yulab-smu.github.io/treedata-book/image-processing-using-magick-package.html#example-1-remove-background-of-images.

You can pass image processing function provided by `magick` package to `geom_image` via the `image_fun` parameter.

Comment: 404 File not found  =(